# Justify Inline elements with Input Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of inline elements (with input text boxes) that should fit within one row. See picture below.

The number of input boxes can vary (dynamically loaded via AJAX), as can the labels of the input boxes. In the example below, it is length x width x height.

The div that the inline elements are in is a dynamic width, which depends on the content above and below this row.

In the event of the screenshot below, how can I get the input boxes to equally increase in width so that the content is justified on both sides? Is there a pure CSS solution?

[image]

```css
.dynamicWidth {
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamicWidth">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>This could be longer or shorter dependending on what is dynamically loaded</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <span>Length</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length"><span> x Width</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="width"><span> x Height</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="height">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not trying using css? display flex and justify-content:space between?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using flexbox's `justify-content` and assigning the value of `space-around` to the div containing the input elements.

```css
.dynamicWidth {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dynamicWidth div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamicWidth">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>This could be longer or shorter dependending on what is dynamically loaded</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <span>Length</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="length"><span> x Width</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="width"><span> x Height</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="height">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're trying to support legacy browsers that don't support flexbox your alternative option would be to wrap each label and input in their own respective divs, give the enclosing parent of those divs a display of `table`  and give the input divs a display of `table-cell` with width percentages of 33.3% (1/3s).

```css
.dynamicWidth {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dynamicWidth div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container {
  width: 33.3%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamicWidth">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>This could be longer or shorter dependending on what is dynamically loaded</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <div class="input-container">
      <span>Length</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="length">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-container">
      <span> x Width</span>  
      <input type="text" placeholder="width">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-container">
      <span> x Height</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="height">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that it's a recent addition to CSS, check if your audience is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Argh! Who needs IE anyway XD! Supplied an alternative solution in addition to the one above.